# Is HashSet<T> Xml Serializable?

Tags: c#, xml, http, serialization, hashset

I would like to serialize an HashSet of IXmlSerializable objects, is HashSet xml serializable?

In my situation, I have the class User and a HashSet called Users. Can I avoid creating a Users class for serializing purposes?

I would liket o pass the hashset as a parameter to the xml serializer.

Is possible to deserialize the xml if it's obtained as an http response? I were thinking about using a MemoryStream, are there other possibilities?

Comment: It has the `Serializable` attribute on it, so I'd say yes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, the Serializable attribute has nothing to do with XML serialization.

Comment: These all seem like really simple tests to write...  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is serializable to XML. Just try:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
set.Add("hello");
set.Add("world");

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HashSet<string>));
string xml;
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    xs.Serialize(writer, set);
    xml = writer.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
}

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var set2 = (HashSet<string>)xs.Deserialize(reader);
    foreach(string s in set2) Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, only a question: how does Deserialize method understand that it have to deserialize to a HashSet instead of an array?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, because the `XmlSerializer` was created for the `HashSet<string>` type (this was specified as a constructor parameter)